# Getting all values used in iterations after the loop finishes in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$DB->newclient(array(
"a" => $_POST["a"],
"b" => $_POST["b"],
"c" => $_POST["c"]
));

function newclient($other = array()){
$keys = array_keys($other);
$columns = implode(",", $keys);
$colVals = implode(",:", $keys);
$sql = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `clients` ($columns) VALUES(:$colVals)");
 foreach($other as $key => $value){
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    echo $value;    // print all values
}
echo $value; // only print first value
$sql->execute();
return true;
}
```

I need to get all values after the loop, but `$value` contains only one value.

Can you help me please?

update:

I just want to insert values into columns so sql->execute is not working because I can not get all values.
the first column is id and auto increment.
if I debug sql:

```
echo "INSERT INTO `clients` ($columns) VALUES($value)";
INSERT INTO `clients` (a,b,c) VALUES(a)

echo var_export($sql->errorInfo()); 
array (
0 => '',
1 => NULL,
2 => NULL,
3 => NULL,
)
```

why does values are null?

Comment: `echo $value; // only print first value` actually prints the *last* value since your loop just overwrites `$value` over and over. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i found my problem, I have encountered an error in my db, really sorry and much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$value` is a scalar string. It's overwritten in every iteration, thus you get only the last value after the loop.

You need to create an array and add a value into the array in every iteration:

```
$sql = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `clients` ($columns) VALUES(:$colVals)");

$allValues = array(); // initialize an array for values

foreach($other as $key => $value){
   $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
   $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
   $allValues[] = $value; // store current value in array
}

var_dump($allValues); // print all values. 
// You may use `print_r` instead of `var_dump`, or whatever
```

---

Besides, you can get all values from an array using [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function, without any loops:

```
$allValues = array_values($other);
var_dump($allValues);
```

Comment: thanks! your answer is right, i can get now all values but when I execute query, can not get all values... update my question

Comment: i found my problem, I have encountered an error in my db, really sorry and much appreciated for your help